# What's the difference between using toFixed and the angular number filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

What are the differences between:

{{ 3.14159 | number : 2 }}
and 
{{ 3.14159.toFixed(2) }}

Does one offer advantages over the other?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Sam, If either answer below helps you, could you click the tick button next to it. If not, you can add a comment on your question as to why not. Dewd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is value still same but masked to 3.14

```
{{ 3.14159 | number : 2 }}
```

but here

```
{{ 3.14159.toFixed(2) }}
```

`toFixed(x)` function is convert a number into a string, keeping only two decimals. for example

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed();
// the output is = 6
```

if you use

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
// the output is = 5.57
```

Note: if the desired number of decimals are higher than the actual number, nulls are added to create the desired decimal length.

Answer (score 4):

The angular number filter does not change the original value of the property, for example:

```
{{ 3.14159 | number : 2 }} // this will give you 3.14 in the dom but the actual value will still be 3.14159
```

When you use a filter it is for display purposes only and does not change the property it just masks it. When you use `toFixed()` you are returning a string of the original number that is set to the specified decimal place which can then be set to another variable.

Comment: I suspect the number filter keeps the number as a number (although angular docs website is down right now, so I can't check). toFixed() casts the number to a string.

Comment: This is true, but my answer still stands true as well. angular filters are masks not setters.

Comment: Yes, filters are masks. It's worth mentioning though, that `.toFixed()` doesn't change the original number either. It returns a string which can be assigned to a variable.